# jQuery pass clicked image src to fancybox popup form

Tags: jquery, forms, autofill

I have a popup form which is activated upon clicking an image, I've used fancybox to have the lightbox effect. What I would like is for one of the form fields to be auto-filled with the clicked images src. I have tried the following but to no effect (nothing in console shopwing an error):

```
jQuery("#storefront li img").click(function() {
    var barimg = jQuery(this).prop("src");
    jQuery("input[name=car]").val(barimg);
});
```

HTML for form:

```
               <div style="display:none">
                    <form method="POST" action="thanks.asp" id="modalbar">
  <div class="formwrapper">
    <label for="name">Name <span class="red2">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName">
    </div>

  <div class="formwrapper">
    <label for="car">Car (Please include <strong>Make</strong> / <strong>Model</strong> / <strong>Year</strong>) <span class="red2">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="Car">
    </div>

    <div class="formwrapper">
    <label for="reg">Reg Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="Reg">
    </div>

  <div class="formwrapper">
    <label for="phone">Telephone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="Tel">

    </div>

  <div class="formwrapper">
    <label for="email">Email Address <span class="red2">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="EmailFrom">

    </div>

  <div class="formwrapper">
    <label for="prefcontact">Preferred Contact Method <span class="red2">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="ConMeth">

    </div>

  <div class="formwrapper">
    <label for="maillist">Join Mailing List</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="MailList" value="Yes" checked="checked">
    </div>

  <div class="field">  
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Form" class="contactsend" />
    <input name="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="contactsend" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Basic fancybox:

```
jQuery(".modaltowbartrigger").fancybox({
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'titleShow'     : false
});
```

any pointers would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: You seem to be missing the `$` on your `input` selector...

Comment: And also, use .prop() instead of .attr() because it's deprecated.

Comment: Thank you both (rookie mistakes!) I have updated the code but still nothing in the form: jQuery("#storefront li img").click(function() {
    var towbarimg = jQuery(this).prop("src");
 jQuery("input[name=car]").val(towbarimg);
});

Comment: Where is the input? In the Fancybox? Is it an iframe you are loading or is the form already loaded?

Comment: it is yes, not an iframe. However thinking about it - would the fact that I have the form wrapped in a hidden div (display: hidden;) be what is preventing it from passing the data?

Comment: if it's hidden it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Can you show some HTML?

Comment: @putvande I have updated the question, thanks

Comment: it's displayed as none; I tought it's set with `visibility: hidden` -  that is the problem; `display:none` means that it does not exists so you cannot set a value for sth that not exist.

Comment: @sTx I have removed the css completely so it is not hidden and still no luck...

Comment: ok, so:

1. name value must be between ' ' and it's "Car" not "car"  `jQuery("input[name='Car']").val(barimg);` 
2. try to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display:none;` just too see if works like this

Comment: Thats cracked it, you're a star! Thanks

Comment: glad it worked :) - but if you need to have it displayed as none I suggest to put the instruction in a timeout, or somehow after the form has been showed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this~~
I think you missed '' in "";

```
jQuery("#storefront li img").click(function() {
    var barimg = jQuery(this).prop("src");
    jQuery("input[name='car']").val(barimg);
});
```

Or  jQuery('input[name="car"]')  will work too, but jQuery("input[name=car]") will not select any element,I think...

Comment: Unofrtunately no change but sTx has cracked it. Thank you!

Comment: try chrome debug mode , add breakpoint at the line "var barimg = jQuery(this).prop("src")" , find out the value of barimg and jQuery("input[name='car']")